# I am unable to render my images even though they get rendered in viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, settings

For some reason I don't get any results when rendering my Images, even though the scenes get rendered in the viewport. Also i sent my .blend file to someone else, trying to figure out what's wrong, but everything worked perfectly for him, so I'm thinking it might be a PC issue, then again, why would it work in the viewport?

Edit: I know this question has been asked already, but the provided solutions have not fixed my problem.

Blend file:[image]

[image: Blank Render Result]

[image: Rendered in Viewport]

Any ideas on how to fix this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: hello could you please share your file (or at least a part of it): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It looks like you have a couple of objects hidden in the outliner, there's viewport visibility and render visibility - worth checking perhaps

Answer (score -1):

If you've been using keyframes at all and you moved the camera or object without keyframing them in then it could make a blank render.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that does not seem to be the case, it should show up in the animation workspace, right?

Comment: @rs99 if you have the camera object selected, any keyframes should appear as orange diamonds on the timeline